# Extract UserName from Basic Auth in Mule Custom Policy

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

The requirement is to limit the clientId's based on endpoint/resource. I have referenced this article from Mule4

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Custom-Policy-Example-Limit-Client-IDs-Access-to-Specific-Endpoints-Mule-4

Article demonstrate to  takes the `clientId` from header which is `attributes.headers['client_id']` where as in my req we are passing clientId as part of `userName` in basic Auth. Ideally need to extract the `userName`.Actually when it executes values are passed as base64 encoded form. I know how to extract using dwl

```
 %dw 2.0
  output application/java
  import * from dw::core::Strings
  import * from dw::core::Binaries
  ---
  substringBefore(fromBase64(substringAfter(attributes.headers.authorization default "","Basic ")),":")
```

I'm trying to fit in the custom policy to extract the userName to validate as like the above mentioned in dwl. Not getting any success.

Also refered this article from Mulesoft, it says how to extract client Id from header,payload,quaryParam when it comes to `Obtaining Credentials using Basic Authorization header` it skipped the expression filed.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/client-id-based-policies

How to extract the userName from Basic Auth in the Mule Custom Policy way?

Any thoughts would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Please let em know if my question is not clear.
Using Mule4.4.

Edit to give more details:

Reference having the policy like below

```
  <http-policy:proxy name="{{{policyId}}}-custom-policy">
    <http-policy:source>
        <try>
              <choice  >
                {{#clientIDs}}
                  <when expression="#[&#39;{{{.}}}&#39;=={{{clientIdExpression}}}]">
                    <logger level="INFO" message="Route Found"/>
                  </when>
```

where `{{{clientIdExpression}}}` is picked from YAML value `attributes.headers['client_id']`

so I have replaced choice expression above `#[&#39;{{{.}}}&#39;=={{{clientIdExpression}}}]` with the dwl expression  to get username from auth and compare

```
  <http-policy:proxy name="{{{policyId}}}-custom-policy">
    <http-policy:source>
        <try>
              <choice  >
                {{#clientIDs}}
                  <when expression="#[%dw 2.0
output application/java
import * from dw::core::Strings
import * from dw::core::Binaries
var extractClientID =    substringBefore
 (fromBase64(substringAfter(attributes.headers.authorization default "","Basic ")),":")
---
if ('{{{.}}}' == extractClientID) true else false ">
                    <logger level="INFO" message="Route Found"/>
                  </when>
```

It gives me error loading `c:/... Element type "when" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". at org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:56) at org.mule.runtime.core.api.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:84)`

Do you know how to use dataweave inside custom policy? Meaning annotation start and end tag?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What results are you getting? Have you validated the DataWeave expression outside the policy?

Comment: Did you log the value inside the policy? If you are passing it to the flow, be aware of the `propagateMessageTransformations="true"` param https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/custom-policy-4-reference

Comment: @aled Given more details in question. Yes I tested dw outside it will extract the clientid where as if i put inside choice it dont work in the regular way. Any thought on using dwl in custom policy?

Comment: @JorgeGarcia I thought it would pop out in the same fashion as it do in anypoint studio. I have added error details in the page.

Comment: The actual specific error you are getting now may be because you are using double quotes for the XML attribute `expression` but inside you are not escaping the double quotes. You may want to use single quotes for one thing and double quotes for the other. Also, I recomend writing this on a simple Mule flow using the UI and then copy the XML (already validated) to the policy removing the `doc:..` atributes and changing the placeholders you need.

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your when expression string.

The expression string has a square bracket that needs to be closed -

```
<when expression="#[]" >
```

Comment: typo questions should be closed. click flag -> needs improvement -> community-specific reason -> typo